# using scanf to read a string and an int separated by /

Tags: c, scanf

The input consists a string and an integer, which are separated by a `'/'`, like this:

```
hello/17
```

And I want to read the input into a string and an `int`, like this:

```
char str[20];
int num;
scanf("%s/%d", str, &num);  // this how I tried to do it.
```

I can't seem to make it, any advice?

Comment: Interesting question. `scanf` may have something to simulate matching more than with just `%s`.

Comment: Don't forget to provide a field width when using `%s` or `%[` conversions!  We don't like buffer overflows...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`scanf` awaits a whitespace terminated string when it tries to read `%s`.

Try to specify the forbidden character set directly:

```
  scanf("%19[^/]/%d", str, &num);
```

You can read more about the formating codes [here](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/C/scanf.html)

Answer (score 9):

You only need to run the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char str[20] = {'\0'};
    int count, num = 42;

    count = sscanf ("hello/17", "%s/%d", str, &num);

    printf ("String was '%s'\n", str);
    printf ("Number was %d\n", num);
    printf ("Count  was %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

to see why this is happening. The output is:

```
String was 'hello/17'
Number was 42
Count  was 1
```

The reason has to do with the `%s` format specifier. From C99 `7.19.6.2 The fscanf function` (largely unchanged in C11, and the italics are mine):

> `s`: matches a sequence of *non-white-space* characters.

Since `/` is not white space, it gets  included in the string bit, as does the `17` for the same reason. That's also indicated by the fact that `sscanf` returns `1`, meaning that only *one* item was scanned.

What you'll then be looking for is something that scans any characters *other* than `/` into the string (including white space). The same section of the standard helps out there as well:

> `[`: matches a nonempty sequence of characters from a set of expected characters (the scanset). The conversion specifier includes all subsequent characters in the format string, up to and including the matching right bracket (]). The characters between the brackets (the scanlist) compose the scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex (^), in which case the scanset contains all characters that do not appear in the scanlist between the circumflex and the right bracket.

In other words, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    char str[20] = {'\0'};
    int count, num = 42;

    count = sscanf ("hello/17", "%[^/]/%d", str, &num);

    printf ("String was '%s'\n", str);
    printf ("Number was %d\n", num);
    printf ("Count  was %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

which gives you:

```
String was 'hello'
Number was 17
Count  was 2
```

---

One other piece of advice: never *ever* use `scanf` with an unbounded `%s` or `%[`; you're asking for a buffer overflow attack. If you want a robust user input function, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

Once you have it in as a string, you can `sscanf` it to your heart's content without worrying about buffer overflow (since you've limited the size on input).

Answer (score 0):

Could be like that:

```
char str[20];
int num;

scanf("%19[^/]%*c%d", str, &num);
```

`%*c` reads one character and discards it